# how do i select datepicker using page-object-gem and jqueryui_widgets

Tags: ruby, datepicker, watir, page-object-gem

I'm trying to use jqueryui_widgets combined with page-object-gem to test a datepicker, but I am failing on the first step.

```
  on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker = date
```

I get this error:

```
Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException: object is read only {:id=>"datepicker", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :type=>"(any text type)"}
./features/step_definitions/datepicker_steps.rb:8:in `/^I enter the date "([^\"]*)"$/'
./features/has_a_datepicker.feature:8:in `When I enter the date "10/05/2015"'
```

has_a_date_picker_page.rb  ( jqueryui_widgets example [datepicker_page.rb](https://github.com/cheezy/jqueryui_widgets/blob/master/features/support/pages/datepicker_page.rb) )

```
class HasADatepickerPage
  include PageObject

  jqueryui_datepicker(:the_datepicker, :id => 'datepicker')

end
```

Questions:

1. What do I need to do prior to on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker = date ?
2. What do I need to do prior to on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker_select_day day ?

I cloned the jqueryui_widgets project, ran datepicker feature test, works fine. I modelled my solution as closely as I could to it.

I included snipets from my html page and the rest of the glory details I could think of below.

Thanks,
Tim

The Gory Details

my site html vs ( jqueryui_widgets example [datepicker.html](https://github.com/cheezy/jqueryui_widgets/blob/master/features/html/datepicker.html) )

```
<div class="forms">
<div class="ajaxformitem" rel="Please select the number of passengers traveling">
<div class="ajaxformitem" rel="Please Enter the Date of Travel" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
<div class="ajaxformitemleft">
<div class="ajaxformitemright">
<input id="datepicker" class="corner required hasDatepicker" type="text" placeholder="Pick Up Date" value="" readonly="true" name="PickUpTime[Date]"/>
<select id="hour" class="corner required" name="PickUpTime_Hour">
<select id="minute" class="corner required" name="PickUpTime[Mnute]">
</div>
</div>
```

ui-datepicker-div:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="position: absolute; top: 199px; left: 635.5px; z-index: 12; display: block;">
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" title="Prev" onclick="DP_jQuery_1440799766008.datepicker._adjustDate('#datepicker', -1, 'M');">
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all" title="Next" onclick="DP_jQuery_1440799766008.datepicker._adjustDate('#datepicker', +1, 'M');">
<div class="ui-datepicker-title">
</div>
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
<thead>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

has_a_datepicker.feature   - same as example

```
Feature: Using the JQueryUI Datepicker widget

  Background:
    Given I am on the has datepicker page


  Scenario: Testing datepicker jqueryui_widgets
    When I enter the date "10/05/2015"
    And I select day "25"
    Then the date should be "10/25/2015"
```

datepicker_steps.rb  -  the_datepicker vs (datepicker_one and datepicker_two)

```
Given(/^I am on the has datepicker page$/) do
  visit(HomePage)
  on(HomePage).select_radio_for 'From'
  on(HomePage).select_service 'Airport'
end

When(/^I enter the date "([^\"]*)"$/) do |date|
  on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker = date
end

And(/^I select day "(\d+)"$/) do |day|
  on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker_select_day day
end

Then(/^the date should be "([^\"]*)"$/) do |day|
  #on(DatepickerPage).datepicker_one.should == day
  expect(on(HasADatepickerPage).the_datepicker).to eql day
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selecting a Date**

If you look at the [datepicker methods](https://github.com/cheezy/jqueryui_widgets/blob/master/lib/jqueryui_widgets/datepicker.rb), all of the interactions with the calendar assume that the calendar is already displayed. If you look at the gem's test (features), you will see they always inputted the text field first, which opens the calendar. Only after that do the tests try to interact with the calendar.

However, since your text field is read-only, you cannot input the text field to trigger the popup. As a result, you need to click the text field. The datepicker accessor creates a `{name}_element` method for accessing the text field. Therefore, you can do:

```
page.the_datepicker_element.click
page.the_datepicker_select_day('15')
```

**Setting a Date**

The `{name}=` method for directly setting the date will not work for your control. The method simply types into the text field, which being read-only is not valid.

You seem to have 2 options:

1. Click the Next/Previous Month controls until you get the right month and then select the day.
2. Use JavaScript to input the text field directly.

Unless there are events the application excepts to be raised when inputting the date, I would suggest going with option 2. It is quicker and less error prone. While it does not mimic the user, testing the interactions within a jQuery widget should not be your responsibility.

```
date = '08/13/2015'
page.execute_script("arguments[0].value='#{date}';", page.the_datepicker_element)
```

If you really want to input the value like a user:

```
# These libraries are added to help with doing date comparisons
require 'date'
require 'active_support/time'

# The date you want to set
date = '12/13/2015'

# Open the calender
page.the_datepicker_element.click

# Determine if we need to navigate to a prior or future month
final_date = Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
current_date = Date.strptime(
    "#{page.the_datepicker_month} #{page.the_datepicker_year}",
    '%B %Y'
)
difference = (final_date.year * 12 + final_date.month) - (current_date.year * 12 + current_date.month)

# Navigate to the required month/year
if difference < 0
    difference.abs.times { page.the_datepicker_previous_month }
else
    difference.abs.times { page.the_datepicker_next_month }
end

# Select the day
page.the_datepicker_select_day(final_date.day.to_s)
```

As you can see, having to click the next/previous controls adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: As I said below page.the_datepicker_element.click does get things going - thanks to both justin and titus. To keep things simple I modified my local copy of the jqueryui_widgets datepicker files. I have set the first datepicker to include readonly = 'true' and behavior is same as my page. I got your date script to work also, but I'm still working on it. Sorry delays,  just started using ruby/watir/page-object last week. btw you're correct the next/prev buttons is more complex - I did similar in java, but so many more lines of code. ruby rocks. For me date = tomorrow will make test versatile

Comment: Having gone in circles for a bit I went back to stock version of gem and test code. My observations are consistent with your initial paragraph above: All Must begin with ".. enter date ...", this effectively does The Click - you can't start a scenario with ..  I select day ... For my readonly, I try to add  only the element.click and your script - timing issues arise. question becomes - where to put The Click? what happens if i put The Click after  enter date - ie two clicks. or conditional click based on datepicker visible. Option #2 is best for me. I will update code on complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your ui-datepicker-div has: `<input id="datepicker" readonly="true">`
Watir won't let you send text to an element that is set to be readonly. Remove that attribute and this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have control over the html content. I believe its that way because I haven't "clicked" it, which is the thing I don't know how to do. I have implemented this with java/webdriver using the same locator. In that case after element click, i see the datepicker and can manipulate it. Also, I just checked, when I click it manually the readonly = true is unchanged.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment. The readonly indicates I can't type a date into the field directly, this field reflects the selection made by using the datepicker. It is correct that the example html doesn't have the readonly = true attribute. I hope this isn't the cause of my problem, as I said it works fine using java/webdriver.

Comment: Watir makes a number of additional checks that java does not. The intention is to give better error messages. Try the_datepicker.click or the_datepicker_element.click first

Comment: thanks for the update! the_datepicker_element.click is the ticket. I will add more comments to justin's answer above